# Opening charting software (ninjatrader) through personal source code

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C code that can open ninjatrader and export data from it without my having to do anything but open the program and enter what stocks I want. The problem I'm having is that when I try to open "C:/Program Files (x86)/NinjaTrader 7/bin64/NinjaTrader.exe" in my code, I get an fopen error: Permission Denied. My question is if there is a way for my code to open and navigate ninjatrader, or will I have to do that all manually. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to "call" an external program, you don't open the executable file and read it into memory, you use functions such as the WIN32 function [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [`system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy should go with `system()` command instead of `fopen()`

Based on your requirements i suggest you to use any **scripting language** for such automation.

Linux/windows `shell/Bash script` or `python` is best for you